# How to use Cardinality of @Property annotation in OSGI Declarative Services

Tags: java, osgi, osgi-bundle, apache-felix, declarative-services

I'm Migrating Apache Felix SCR Annotations to OSGI Declarative Services[AEM]. While Migration I cant find exact replacement for cardinality in DS .

Existing SCR Implementation :

```
@Component (ds = true, immediate = true, metatype = false, policy = ConfigurationPolicy.OPTIONAL)
@Service (SampleService.class)
public class SampleServiceImpl implements SampleService
{
   private static final int VECTOR = Integer.MIN_VALUE + 1;

    @Property (value = REPOSTING_PATTERN, cardinality = VECTOR,description = "Event reposting pattern for QueuePosting ")
    private static String EVENT_REPOSTING_PATTERN = "eventRepostingPattern";
}
```

Now it is migrated as Below in OSGi Declarative services

```
  @Component (configurationPolicy = ConfigurationPolicy.OPTIONAL, immediate = true, service =SampleService.class,
   property = {SampleServiceImpl .EVENT_REPOSTING_PATTERN +"="+SampleServiceImpl .EVENT_REPOSTING_PATTERN_VALUE })
  public class SampleServiceImpl implements SampleService
   {
     private static String EVENT_REPOSTING_PATTERN = "eventRepostingPattern";
     private static String EVENT_REPOSTING_PATTERN = "eventRepostingPatternValue";
   }
```

In DS annotation Implementation How I have to map the parameter **cardinality** which is present in @Property.Kindly suggest me

Answer (score 0):

[Documentation](http://felix.apache.org/documentation/subprojects/apache-felix-maven-scr-plugin/scr-annotations.html) about the `@Property` and `cardinality` is confusing as usual but I am assuming based on [this](https://experienceleaguecommunities.adobe.com/t5/adobe-experience-manager/convert-felix-properties-property-to-osgi-annotations/qaq-p/295034) that these are somehow related to configurations. You can setup Type-safe configurations for your service(s) with `@Designate` and `@ObjectClassDefinition` annotations. The `cardinality` option can be found in `@AttributeDefinition` annotation.

**ExampleServiceimpl.java**

```java
import org.osgi.framework.BundleContext;
import org.osgi.service.component.annotations.Activate;
import org.osgi.service.component.annotations.Component;
import org.osgi.service.metatype.annotations.Designate;

@Component( immediate = true, service = ExampleService.class )
@Designate( ocd = ExampleServiceConfig.class )
public class ExampleServiceImpl implements ExampleService {
    
    @Activate
    public void activateService(BundleContext context, ExampleServiceConfig config){
        System.out.println(config.some_config());
    }
}
```

**ExampleServiceConfig.java**

```java
import org.osgi.service.metatype.annotations.AttributeDefinition;
import org.osgi.service.metatype.annotations.ObjectClassDefinition;

@ObjectClassDefinition(
    name = " Example service Configuration"
)
public @interface ExampleServiceConfig {
    
    @AttributeDefinition( cardinality = 1 )
    String some_config() default "default value";
}
```

Now as disclaimer I've never managed to used `@AttributeDefinition` or `cardinality` annotation myself yet so might be off here. Encountered the `cardinality` option when I tried to use `@AttributeDefinition` to see if I could use it to make my service configurations pretty in hawtio but probably missing some steps.

But hopefully this points you to right direction.